# How to fill a font text with patterns from images and transition between them?

Tags: html, image, css

I am using a custom font (generated through IconMoon) for my project. So far, I have managed to fill the font with a custom patterns (diagnol-left.gif, diagnol-right.gif, blanc.gif) and transition between them. However, the transition is not going gradually as I wish, moreover it jumps from one pattern to another. How can I make it gradually changing?

**html**

```
<i class="icon-custom button-home"></i>
```

**css**

```
.button-home {
  color: #00D7FF;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
  url("/tabsnew/www/img/blanc.gif") repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-animation: animation-button 30000ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: animation-button 30000ms infinite;
  -o-animation: animation-button 30000ms infinite;
  animation: animation-button 30000ms infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/blanc.gif") repeat;
    }
     25%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/diagnol-left.gif") repeat;
    }
     50%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/diagnol-right.gif") repeat;
    }
     75%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/blanc.gif") repeat;
    }
     100%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/blanc.gif") repeat;
    }
}
@keyframes animation-button {
    0%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/blanc.gif") repeat;
    }
     25%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/diagnol-left.gif") repeat;
    }
     50%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/diagnol-right.gif") repeat;
    }
     75%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/blanc.gif") repeat;
    }
     100%   {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      url("/tabsnew/www/img/blanc.gif") repeat;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking we need a demo with the actual image here but it's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do. I'd love to see an image of the **intended result**.

Comment: Hi, actually I try to transition image patterns on an image font. The code above actually works (oops), but the transition is not being processed gradually - it jumps from one state to another. I am going to update my question and code.

Comment: You can't transition background images (as far as I know). It's not an animatable property,